# Write to folder with one user via SFTP, but read only with other user

Tags: centos, sftp

I have a need to set up an SFTP server which is multi user.  The users in question have read-only access to their chrooted folders.

I need to be able to put files to these folders via SFTP with a different, administrative user account.

(For the purposes of this question I'll call my read-only sftp user example **user1** and my member of sudoers admin account **admin1**)

I followed instructions here -

http://terminaltwister.com/setting-up-a-chrooted-sftp-server-on-centos-7-systemd/

but instead of `chown root` on the user's directory I did `chown admin1`

I could not log via sftp using the user1's credentials.

I then did `chown root` on the user's home folder (to follow more closely the instructions on the terminaltwister article) and *was* then able to log in as user1 via sftp, but when logging in as admin1 I was not able to put files to user1's folders.

I've disabled Root login via SSH (it's recommended) so I don't want to use root to *put* the files. I want to be able to put files to my users folders using admin1, and have each user be able to log in via sftp and have read-only access to their respective folder.

I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this.   Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I created a new group...

`sudo groupadd adminacces`

Changed the group of the folder I want to write to

`sudo chgrp adminaccess /home/user1/data`

I added the admin1 user to the group that owns the folder I want to write to (the user account is NOT a member of that group)

`sudo usermod -a -G adminaccess admin1`

Then I set the group, but NOT the owner of the folder to have write access.

`sudo chmod 575 /home/user1/data`